# Unlock the reading pane in outlook 2016

Tags: powershell, cmd, outlook, registry, regedit

How do you write a script to change a registry key? What I am trying to do is have a script I can run to unlock the reading pane in outlook 2016.

The path of the registry key is:

> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\options
>   disablereadingpane REG_DWORD 0x00000001 (1)

And I need to change the 1 to a 0. In the 0x00000001

Any help getting started with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is that the code? can you explain at all what is going on and submit as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment was faulty it's `add` not `edit`.

reg.exe is the command line registry manipulation tool. See [reg.exe /?](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html)

You may first check if the key exists and what value / data it has.

```
Reg Query "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\options"
```

To `add`a key/value/data pair

```
Reg add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\options" /v disablereadingpane /t REG_DWORD /d 0x0
```

optionally you may add a `/f`  force option to overwrte current content.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this, if you're using powershell. It's pretty self explanatory

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\options -Name disablereadingpane -Value 0
```